# Parallel write to array slower than serial write using OmniThreadLibrary

Tags: multithreading, delphi, omnithreadlibrary

I am working on an implementation of the Differential Evolution optimization algorithm, and want to speed up the calculation time by calculating population members in parallel.
I am using the OmniThread library, and have successfully parallelized my loop, only to find that it runs SLOWER than the serial implementation.

I have reduced the code to its essence to test the parallelization, and the reduced version exhibits the same problem: the parallel version is slower than the serial one.

The key is that I pass multiple dynamic arrays to which output should be written for each member of the population. Each array has one of the dimensions dedicated to the population member, so for each population member a different set of array indices is accessed. This also means that in the parallel implementation no 2 threads will write to the same array element.

Below the code I used to test (the actual code in the Differential Evolution has a `DoWork` procedure with even more `const` parameters and `var` arrays)

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

type
  TGoalFunction = reference to function(const X, B: array of extended): extended;
  TArrayExtended1D = array of extended;
  TArrayExtended2D = array of TArrayExtended1D;

  TClassToTest = class abstract
  private
    class procedure DoWork(const AGoalFunction: TGoalFunction; const AInputArray: TArrayExtended2D; var AOutputArray1: TArrayExtended1D; var AOutputArray2: TArrayExtended2D; const AIndex, AIndex2: integer);
  public
    class procedure RunSerial;
    class procedure RunParallel;
  end;

function HyperSphere(const X, B: array of extended): extended;

const
  DIMENSION1 = 5000;
  DIMENSION2 = 5000;
  LOOPS = 10;

implementation

uses
  OtlParallel;

function HyperSphere(const X, B: array of extended): extended;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  for I := 0 to Length(X) - 1 do
    Result := Result + X[I]*X[I];
end;

{ TClassToTest }

class procedure TClassToTest.DoWork(const AGoalFunction: TGoalFunction; const AInputArray: TArrayExtended2D; var AOutputArray1: TArrayExtended1D; var AOutputArray2: TArrayExtended2D; const AIndex, AIndex2: integer);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  AOutputArray1[AIndex] := AGoalFunction(AInputArray[AIndex], []);
  for I := 0 to Length(AOutputArray2[AIndex]) - 1 do
    AOutputArray2[AIndex, I] := Random*AIndex2;
end;

class procedure TClassToTest.RunParallel;
var
  LGoalFunction: TGoalFunction;
  LInputArray: TArrayExtended2D;
  LOutputArray1: TArrayExtended1D;
  LOutputArray2: TArrayExtended2D;
  I, J, K: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(LInputArray, DIMENSION1, DIMENSION2);
  for I := 0 to DIMENSION1 - 1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to DIMENSION2 - 1 do
      LInputArray[I, J] := Random;
  end;
  SetLength(LOutputArray1, DIMENSION1);
  SetLength(LOutputArray2, DIMENSION1, DIMENSION2);

  LGoalFunction := HyperSphere;

  for I := 0 to LOOPS - 1 do
  begin
    Parallel.ForEach(0, DIMENSION1 - 1).Execute(
      procedure (const value: integer)
      begin
        DoWork(LGoalFunction, LInputArray, LOutputArray1, LOutputArray2, value, I);
      end
    );

    for J := 0 to DIMENSION1 - 1 do
    begin
      for K := 0 to DIMENSION2 - 1 do
        LInputArray[J, K] := LOutputArray2[J, K];
    end;
  end;
end;

class procedure TClassToTest.RunSerial;
var
  LGoalFunction: TGoalFunction;
  LInputArray: TArrayExtended2D;
  LOutputArray1: TArrayExtended1D;
  LOutputArray2: TArrayExtended2D;
  I, J, K: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(LInputArray, DIMENSION1, DIMENSION2);
  for I := 0 to DIMENSION1 - 1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to DIMENSION2 - 1 do
      LInputArray[I, J] := Random;
  end;
  SetLength(LOutputArray1, DIMENSION1);
  SetLength(LOutputArray2, DIMENSION1, DIMENSION2);

  LGoalFunction := HyperSphere;

  for I := 0 to LOOPS - 1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to DIMENSION1 - 1 do
    begin
      DoWork(LGoalFunction, LInputArray, LOutputArray1, LOutputArray2, J, I);
    end;

    for J := 0 to DIMENSION1 - 1 do
    begin
      for K := 0 to DIMENSION2 - 1 do
        LInputArray[J, K] := LOutputArray2[J, K];
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

I was expecting a speedup of around x6 on my 8-core processor, but was faced with a slight slowdown. What should I change to get the speedup from running the `DoWork` procedure in parallel?

Note that I'd prefer to keep the actual work in the `DoWork` procedure, since I have to be able to call the same algorithm with and without parallelization (boolean flag) while keeping the body of the code shared for easy maintenance

Comment: Sounds maybe like false sharing. Although a quick scan suggests each task works on a different array, so that would not explain it. Are your tasks large enough for threading to help? You'd also get a worthwhile speed up if you would refrain from using the appalling `Extended` data type. It's alignment properties will hurt you badly. Use `Double`.

Comment: @David The task presented here would perform `Result := Result + X[I]*X[I];` 5000 times, and this task would also be done 5000 times per outer loop (which is done 10 times).

The actual task in the DE algorithm is or can be certainly much larger, but it is up to the user of the implementation to determine if the task is big enough to warant parallelization (hence it should be implemented both in serial and parallel)

Comment: FWIW Sqr is better than X*X I think, and Random is not threadsafe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not threadsafe and Slow, the problem should be it (Random)

Comment: +1 for a wonderfully written question with an excellent SSCCE.

Comment: I do work with genetic programming (not in Delphi) and this is a good example of an "embarrassingly parallel" problem that is better off being done with processes rather than threads. There's no need to be sharing data between population members so multiprocessing gives you the performance boost without the obsession over whether this, that or the other thing is thread-safe or not. Unfortunately not a lot of languages or their third-party libraries have good support for multiprocessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the lack of thread safety of `Random`. The implementation of which is:

```
// global var
var
  RandSeed: Longint = 0;    { Base for random number generator }

function Random: Extended;
const
  two2neg32: double = ((1.0/$10000) / $10000);  // 2^-32
var
  Temp: Longint;
  F: Extended;
begin
  Temp := RandSeed * $08088405 + 1;
  RandSeed := Temp;
  F  := Int64(Cardinal(Temp));
  Result := F * two2neg32;
end;
```

Because `RandSeed` is a global variable, which is modified by a call to `Random`, the threads end up having contended writes to `RandSeed`. And those contended writes cause your performance problem. They effectively serialize your parallel code. Severely enough to make it slower than the true serial code.

Add the code below to the top of the implementation section of your unit and you'll see the difference:

```
threadvar
  RandSeed: Longint;

function Random: Double;
const
  two2neg32: double = ((1.0/$10000) / $10000);  // 2^-32
var
  Temp: Longint;
  F: Double;
begin
  Temp := RandSeed * $08088405 + 1;
  RandSeed := Temp;
  F  := Int64(Cardinal(Temp));
  Result := F * two2neg32;
end;
```

With that change to avoid shared, contended writes, you'll find that the parallel version is faster, as expected. You don't get linear scaling with processor count. My guess is that is because your pattern of memory access is sub-optimal in the parallel version of the code.

I'm guessing that you are only using `Random` as a means to generate some data. But if you do need an RNG, you'll want to arrange that each task uses their own private instance of an RNG.

You can also speed up your code a little using `Sqr(X)` rather than `X*X`, and also by switching to `Double` instead of `Extended`.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas OTL uses a thread pool. It doesn't make new threads every time `Parallel.ForEach` is called. I think the task size in the question is quite reasonable. Larger tasks would probably be better all the same.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I don't know. I've not thought about it that much.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas I've honestly not thought about it any more than what I wrote.

Comment: This indeed seems to solve the scaling issue. However the serial implementation seems to be 25% slower when I do this

Comment: Sorry, slower when you do what? Use a thread local var for the RNG?

Comment: I added `function ThreadSafeRandom: extended;` which uses the `threadvar` to save its Random Seed. Then when I run the serial implementation with `ThreadSafeRandom` it is about 25% slower then running it with `Random`

Comment: Thread local variables are slow. You need to do what I outline in my penultimate paragraph. Also, if you care about perf you'll stop using extended.

Comment: The DE algorithm relies heavily on the generation of random numbers, so I will probably regard it as being extra overhead introduced. I also made it so the serial implementation uses the standard delphi RNG to remove the overhead there. I will be rewriting all my algorithms to use doubles instead.

Comment: Don't use thread local variables in perf critical code. They are expensive.  Arrange that each task has its own RNG with its own state. Then you can avoid that penalty.

Comment: The only reason for me using a thread local was to demonstrate the true issue. I was not meaning to bless that as a good RNG solution. Not least because each thread starts from the same seed. If RNG is important then isn't quality of random numbers also important. Is LCG really appropriate?

Answer (score 3):

Some time ago I was experiencing exactly the same issue. It turned out to be that the bottleneck was that OTL for `Parallel.ForEach` calls with a range creates a hidden enumerator which in cases where the task is very small and the loop is called often is the bottleneck.

A more performant solution looked something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(0, MAXCORES)
    .NumTasks(MAXCORES)
    .Execute(
      procedure (const p:Integer)
      var
        chunkSize : Integer;
        myStart, myEnd : Integer;
        i: Integer;
      begin
        chunkSize := DIMENSION div MAXCORES;
        myStart := p * chunkSize;
        myEnd := min( myStart+chunkSize-1, DIMENSION -1);
        for I := myStart to MyEnd do
          DoSomething(i);
      end);
```

This code scaled up quite linearly regardless of the load within the `DoSomething` call

Comment: I tried that in this case. It made no difference because each task is quite large. This is not the issue in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried running this (with the Random fix and using Doubles) on an i7 (8 hyper threads) and get the times 1650ms for parallel and 5240ms for serial.  Given the code content I don't find this to be particularly unexpected scale up.  The code as it stands will have near to a 100% successful pipeline prediction - all branches predicted, function call returns cached, even cache prefetch working well.  On a typical modern PC this means that the code is probably going to be memory bandwidth limited in which scale up is going to depend a great deal on your memory performance rather than how many cores you have.

The only other issue is potential contention for FPU resources which will be highly dependent on your internal processor architecture.

I suspect that if the workload was more complex a greater scale up would be seen between serial and parallel as the serial version will be losing time to code triggered pipeline breaks whilst the parallel version will remain memory limited.  I've done a fair bit of high performance computing work in Delphi and well optimised algorithms doing simple calculations can become totally memory bound with multi-threaded performance at scale ups of as little as 2 on a good 8 core machine due to memory bandwidth limits.  This sort of issue can be particularly well illustrated if you have over-clocking capability as performance yield from over-clocking the CPU gives a very good indication of the level of memory waits since everything else speeds up proportionally to the over-clocking.

If you want to get into the details of processor architecture and how they impact what you are doing then http://www.agner.org/optimize/ is a good place to learn how much there is to learn.